# angularjs and nodejs social oauth2 flow

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, oauth-2.0

I would like to have the following use case when authenticating a user.

1. If the user is in the path /profile and they are not authenticated, then he must sign in and once signed in, he will be re-directed back to /profile.
2. if the user is in the path /home and they are not authenticated, then he must sign and once authenticated, re-directed back to /home

So far, I've managed to get these steps working:

```
1. user authenticates through linkedin
2. user receives authorization code which is then sent to the node server
3. the node server exchanges the auth code for access token and 
makes linkedin api calls on behalf of the user
4. the node server retrieves user information, creates a json 
web token and then sends it back to the user
```

My issue here is that I'm not sure how to handle the dyanmic re-direct url in angular. Since we lose state. And I don't want popups authentication.
When I set redirect_uri to "http://localhost:3000", it attaches the authorization code to the url and then the server gets this information and sends back the access token.

**My idea**

I will set one specific redirect uri and will make a controller for that url in angular. In that controller, I will send an http request to exchange the authorization code and access token. The server will send back the access token AND linkedin user information which I will store in localStorage. Once authenticated, I will do a $state.go to the proper redirect url. How would I know where to send the user? My idea is to store the initial url the user visited in local storage. So if the user visits /profile and is not authenticated, then I will store /profile in the local storage and then when I hit the call back url I will check localstorage for another redirect url and send the user there.

Please let me know if this is not clear I'll be happy to explain. I'm wondering if there is any flaws to this.